# Base and Spans, linear space

Tags: linear-algebra

Given, K and T are sub-sets of linear space V.

How can I prove that if $ V = Sp(K) + Sp(T)$ then $ K \cup  T$ is NOT a base of V.

I proved that it IS a base of V but the answer says that it's not, can you give me an example of 2 sub-sets K,T that will make their union not a base of V?

Here how I tried:

$ V = R^2 $ , $K = \{(0,1)\} $,$ T = \{(1,0)\}$ then

$V = Sp(K) + Sp(T) = Sp\{(K \cup T)\} = Sp\{(1,0),(0,1)\} = R^2$ , then

$K \cup T = \{(1,0),(0,1)\} = R^2$

Which makes the union of K,T a base of V, but I need your help to find 2 sub-sets that will make it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You surely want to prove, that $K\cup T$ is not necessarily a basis of $V$, since you already gave an example in which it is.

Take $V=\Bbb{R}²$ and  $K,T$ two different bases of $V$, then $Sp(K)+Sp(T)=V$, since $Sp(K)=Sp(T)=V$, but $K\cup T$ has $4$ elements, which are not linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in the problem statement prevents that $0$ is in $K\cup T$.